# Regex to remove onclick="" attributes from HTML elements in ASP.NET C# (Server-side)

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, richtextbox, xss

I'm trying to write a regex function to remove onclick (also onload, onmouseover etc.) attributes from HTML elements. I want to do this on the server side before the HTML is sent to the client.

I have content coming from a Rich Text editor and being displayed on screen in a div, and I want to protect against XSS (Cross Site Scripting). Obviously I can't HTML encode it using Server.HtmlEncode() because the rich text stores the text as HTML markup, so I'm using a blacklisting approach, looking for certain elements such as `<script>` and `<style>`. I'm now trying to look for onclick, onmouseover etc. attributes, so far I have the following:

```
returnVal = Regex.Replace(returnVal, @"\<(.*?)(\ on[a-z]+\=\""?.*?\""?)*(.*?)\>",
               "<$1 $3>", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

...which isn't working, and I've tried a few variations. Basically I want it so that...

```
<p style="font-style: italic" onclick="alert('hacked!!');">Hello World</p>
```

gets turned into...

```
<p style="font-style: italic">Hello World</p>
```

Any ideas? Cheers!

Comment: have you seen here:
http://refactormycode.com/codes/333-sanitize-html ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
returnValue = 
    Regex.Replace(
        returnValue,
        @"(<[\s\S]*?) on.*?\=(['""])[\s\S]*?\2([\s\S]*?>)", 
        delegate(Match match)
        {
            return String.Concat(match.Groups[1].Value, match.Groups[3].Value);
        }, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

HTH

Comment: WOW! Almost perfect except if the onclick attribute appears twice in a single element it'll only remove one of them. I have stuck that code in a while loop using Regex.IsMatch( with your expression and it seems to work. I'll post the code in a separate post in this question, because code samples don't come out very well in these comments.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the old return value and then do a check in the while loop to see if nothing changed if so break out of the loop

```
if(oldContent.Equals(newContent)) { break; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a response to 'Rubens Farias' answer with the code sample I came up with. I used a while loop like so...

```
while (Regex.IsMatch(returnVal, @"(<[\s\S]*?) on.*?\=(['""])[\s\S]*?\2([\s\S]*?>)", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
{
    returnVal = Regex.Replace(returnVal, @"(<[\s\S]*?) on.*?\=(['""])[\s\S]*?\2([\s\S]*?>)",
                    delegate(Match match)
                    {
                        return String.Concat(match.Groups[1].Value, match.Groups[3].Value);
                    }, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

For those interested, here is the entire method I'm using to help protect against XSS...

```
/// <summary>
///     'Helps' protect against XSS (Cross Site Scripting attacks) by stripping out known evil HTML elements
///     such as script and style. Used for outputing text generated by a Rich Text Editor. Doesn't HTML encode!
/// </summary>
/// <param name="input">Input string to strip bad HTML elements from</param>
public static string XSSProtect(string input)
{
    string returnVal = input ?? "";

    returnVal = Regex.Replace(returnVal, @"\<script(.*?)\>(.*?)\<\/script(.*?)\>", "", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    returnVal = Regex.Replace(returnVal, @"\<style(.*?)\>(.*?)\<\/style(.*?)\>", "", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    while (Regex.IsMatch(returnVal, @"(<[\s\S]*?) on.*?\=(['""])[\s\S]*?\2([\s\S]*?>)", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
    {
        returnVal = Regex.Replace(returnVal, @"(<[\s\S]*?) on.*?\=(['""])[\s\S]*?\2([\s\S]*?>)",
                        delegate(Match match)
                        {
                            return String.Concat(match.Groups[1].Value, match.Groups[3].Value);
                        }, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    }

    return returnVal;
}
```

Comment: I must admit I'm a little nervous with this approach, is there any situation where this could end up in an infinite loop?

Comment: I'm not comfortable too; you also should add an extra \s* after and before = symbol, avoiding onclick   =   "alert()"

Answer (score 0):

like this.

```js
if (!String.prototype.replaceAll) {
  (function() {
    String.prototype.replaceAll = function(target, replacement) {
      return this.split(target).join(replacement);
    };
  })();
};

html = html.replaceAll(/onclick.*?\=(['""])[\s\S]*(['""])/ig,"");
console.log(html);
```

result : `<p style="font-style: italic">Hello World</p>`